# Passing variable into different scene in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am doing java fx and i got stuck into passing variable into different FXML scene. so on the first scene controller, LoginController is associated with Login.fxml

```
public class LoginController {

    @FXML private TextField username;
    @FXML private PasswordField password;
    @FXML private Button loginButton;
    @FXML private Label labelStatus;

    @FXML private void handleLoginButton() throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            FXMLLoader mainLoad = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../View/mainscreen.fxml"));
            Parent mainRoot = (Parent) mainLoad.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(mainRoot));
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and when the new scene open i need to set the label based on the username variable that contains the user input. that means we need to pass variables from Login.fxml into mainscreen.fxml through controoler. How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set proper fields in `MainScreenController` through setters. Yo can get controller that is responsible for this fxml by `FXMLoader#getController()` method ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController-- ).

Other ways depends of your application architecture. There should be an object that is responsible for storing that kind of information.

Answer (score 2):

You can get next scene controller and pass variables

```
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("mainscreen.fxml"));
  MainScreenController controller = loader.getController();
  controller.setUserName(userName);
```